# Menu not showing dropdown items

Tags: wordpress, menu, dropdown

I need help on how to get my menu to show sub items when hovering over services and pests, I'm a novice when it comes to wordpress so treat me like a 5 year old please. Thanks

this is the code (i think)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Ozm.png)

[image of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZLkt.png)

havent tried anything yet as i need help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

First of all delete that CSS code. Why display: none on dropdown?
Then go to Wordpress Dashboard appearance -> menu

There you can put multiple subcategories/pages inside the main menu items (drag and drop)

Comment: Yes, Exactly Stefan Says Well, If It's not Working Then You can Install The Another Plugin Menu Like: Mega Menu For Make Your Menu Perfect. So, Remove The Custom CSS Code First...